# Merge rows based on date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to display data based on start date and end date. a code can contain different dates. if any time intervel is continues then I need to merge that rows and display as single row
Here is sample data

```
Code  Start_Date   End_Date     Volume
470   24-Oct-10    30-Oct-10    28
470   17-Oct-10    23-Oct-10     2
470   26-Sep-10     2-Oct-10     2
471   22-Aug-10    29-Aug-10     2
471   15-Aug-10    21-Aug-10     2
```

The output result I want is

```
Code  Start_Date   End_Date     Volume
470   17-Oct-10    30-Oct-10    30
470   26-Sep-10     2-Oct-10     2
471   15-Aug-10    29-Aug-10     4
```

a code can have any no. of time intervels. Pls help. Thank you

Comment: In your sample output (now that it's formated thanks KM) I'm not sure why the the row
470 26-Sep-10 2-Oct-10 2
would not be merged with the other 470 code?

Comment: will any pair of rows (for a particular code) ever have date ranges that actually overlap, or will they always be distinct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your sample data (which I've put in a table called Test), and assuming no overlaps:

```
;with Ranges as (
    select Code,Start_Date,End_Date,Volume from Test
    union all
    select r.Code,r.Start_Date,t.End_Date,(r.Volume + t.Volume)
    from
        Ranges r
            inner join
        Test t
            on
                r.Code = t.Code and
                DATEDIFF(day,r.End_Date,t.Start_Date) = 1
), ExtendedRanges as (
select Code,MIN(Start_Date) as Start_Date,End_Date,MAX(Volume) as Volume
from Ranges
group by Code,End_Date
)
select Code,Start_Date,MAX(End_Date),MAX(Volume)
from ExtendedRanges
group by Code,Start_Date
```

Explanation:

The Ranges [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) contains all rows from the original table (because some of them might be relevant) and all rows we can form by joining ranges together (both original ranges, and any intermediate ranges we construct - we're doing recursion here).

Then ExtendedRanges (poorly named) finds, for any particular End_Date, the earliest Start_Date that can reach it.

Finally, we query this second CTE, to find, for any particular Start_Date, the latest End_Date that is associated with it.

These two queries combine to basically filter the Ranges CTE down to "the widest possible Start_Date/End_Date pair" in each set of overlapping date ranges.

Sample data setup:

```
create table Test (
    Code int not null,
    Start_Date date not null,
    End_Date date not null,
    Volume int not null
)
insert into Test(Code,  Start_Date,   End_Date,     Volume)
select 470,'24-Oct-10','30-Oct-10',28 union all
select 470,'17-Oct-10','23-Oct-10',2 union all
select 470,'26-Sep-10','2-Oct-10',2 union all
select 471,'22-Aug-10','29-Aug-10',2 union all
select 471,'15-Aug-10','21-Aug-10',2
go
```

Answer (score 3):

if I understand your request, you're looking for something like:

```
select code, min(Start_date), max(end_date), sum(volume)
from yourtable
group by code
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. but your query display single row per code. in data there is gap between 2-Oct-2010 to 17-oct-2010. so we should get 2 rows for code 470

Comment: Ok, but technically there's a gap of 24 hours between the first and second row in your sample as well.  If there is to be no gap of time between one row and the next, then the start time and end time should be equal, no?

Comment: yes, exactly. if there is morethan 24hrs then diff rows else merge it