# Calculating user's unique set of start end times

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need assistance with following situation.

This table is on SQL Server 2005. we also have access to SQL Server 2008, if you feel some function in 2008 will be helpful. I can do that as a last option though. :)

I have log in log out times of 100+ users to a system. They can log in to different channels at the same time.

I need there end to end log in log out times irrespective of Channel

I'm guessing this can be accomplished by a stored procedure. But I'm open to any other option if it does not hit performance.

Below `AgentResults2` is my base table.

`AgentOutcome` table is how I want the out put to look like.

An example of base table

```
FUser_id           FLoginDt                 FLogoutDt
30001              2012-02-17 12:32:15.473  2012-02-17 14:15:36.547
30001              2012-02-17 12:49:48.177  2012-02-17 14:10:01.097
30001              2012-02-17 14:30:49.293  2012-02-17 15:41:02.387
```

This user logged in to a channel at 12.32 stayed there till 14:15 within that period he also logged in to another channelat 12:49 and stayed there till 14:10. And did a fresh login at 14:30 till 15:41. I want to get two rows from here which is

```
FUser_id           FLoginDt                 FLogoutDt
30001              2012-02-17 12:32:15.473  2012-02-17 14:15:36.547
30001              2012-02-17 14:30:49.293  2012-02-17 15:41:02.387
```

It gets complicated when you look at user 39395

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY

IF OBJECT_ID('#AgentResults2', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #AgentResults2;

CREATE TABLE #AgentResults2  (FUser_id  varchar(48), FLoginDt datetime, FLogoutDt DateTime)

Insert Into #AgentResults2 (FUser_id , FLoginDt, FLogoutDt ) 
Select '30001','17/02/2012 8:09:23.117 AM' ,'17/02/2012 8:39:28.527 AM' UNION ALL
Select '30001','17/02/2012 8:50:26.087 AM','17/02/2012 9:31:32.040 AM' UNION ALL
Select '30001','17/02/2012 10:28:42.430 AM','17/02/2012 10:54:13.880 AM' UNION ALL
Select '30001','17/02/2012 10:59:20.567 AM','17/02/2012 12:00:36.030 PM' UNION ALL
Select '30001','17/02/2012 12:32:15.473 PM','17/02/2012 2:15:36.547 PM' UNION ALL
Select '30001','17/02/2012 12:49:48.177 PM','17/02/2012 2:10:01.097 PM' UNION ALL
Select '30001','17/02/2012 2:30:49.293 PM','17/02/2012 3:41:02.387 PM' UNION ALL
Select '30001','17/02/2012 3:44:05.800 PM','17/02/2012 4:01:33.613 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39300','17/02/2012 8:06:31.250 AM','17/02/2012 3:51:31.930 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39300','17/02/2012 10:15:08.923 AM','17/02/2012 10:21:29.833 AM' UNION ALL
Select '39363','17/02/2012 9:58:44.287 AM','17/02/2012 11:20:08.950 AM' UNION ALL
Select '39363','17/02/2012 11:20:29.203 AM','17/02/2012 1:27:36.717 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39363','17/02/2012 1:27:36.717 PM','17/02/2012 3:05:12.383 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39363','17/02/2012 3:05:31.527 PM','17/02/2012 4:57:13.733 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39363','17/02/2012 4:57:44.640 PM','17/02/2012 5:59:20.273 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39395','17/02/2012 9:37:14.353 AM','17/02/2012 10:15:52.397 AM' UNION ALL
Select '39395','17/02/2012 10:15:28.427 AM','17/02/2012 10:58:47.080 AM' UNION ALL
Select '39395','17/02/2012 10:57:03.590 AM','17/02/2012 11:53:47.933 AM' UNION ALL
Select '39395','17/02/2012 11:51:31.567 AM','17/02/2012 2:26:27.640 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39395','17/02/2012 2:31:30.247 PM','17/02/2012 4:04:44.217 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39395','17/02/2012 4:10:49.013 PM','17/02/2012 4:11:26.983 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39395','17/02/2012 4:17:16.813 PM','17/02/2012 5:55:47.187 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39395','17/02/2012 4:55:25.900 PM','17/02/2012 5:26:07.310 PM' ;

Select * from #AgentResults2;

IF OBJECT_ID('#AgentOutcome', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #AgentOutcome;

CREATE TABLE #AgentOutcome  (FUser_id  varchar(48), FLoginDt datetime, FLogoutDt DateTime)

Insert Into #AgentOutcome (FUser_id , FLoginDt, FLogoutDt ) 

Select '30001','17/02/2012 8:09:23.117 AM','17/02/2012 8:39:28.527 AM' UNION ALL
Select '30001','17/02/2012 8:50:26.087 AM','17/02/2012 9:31:32.040 AM' UNION ALL
Select '30001','17/02/2012 10:28:42.430 AM','17/02/2012 10:54:13.880 AM' UNION ALL
Select '30001','17/02/2012 10:59:20.567 AM','17/02/2012 12:00:36.030 PM' UNION ALL
Select '30001','17/02/2012 12:32:15.473 PM','17/02/2012 2:15:36.547 PM' UNION ALL
Select '30001','17/02/2012 2:30:49.293 PM','17/02/2012 3:41:02.387 PM' UNION ALL
Select '30001','17/02/2012 3:44:05.800 PM','17/02/2012 4:01:33.613 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39300','17/02/2012 8:06:31.250 AM','17/02/2012 3:51:31.930 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39363','17/02/2012 9:58:44.287 AM','17/02/2012 11:20:08.950 AM' UNION ALL
Select '39363','17/02/2012 11:20:29.203 AM','17/02/2012 3:05:12.383 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39363','17/02/2012 3:05:31.527 PM','17/02/2012 4:57:13.733 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39363','17/02/2012 4:57:44.640 PM','17/02/2012 5:59:20.273 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39395','17/02/2012 9:37:14.353 AM','17/02/2012 2:26:27.640 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39395','17/02/2012 2:31:30.247 PM','17/02/2012 4:04:44.217 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39395','17/02/2012 4:10:49.013 PM','17/02/2012 4:11:26.983 PM' UNION ALL
Select '39395','17/02/2012 4:17:16.813 PM','17/02/2012 5:55:47.187 PM' ;

Select * from #AgentOutcome;

DROP TABLE #AgentResults2;
DROP TABLE #AgentOutcome;
```

I have checked other related topics, they do come close but are more specific to aggregation and satisfied with min start & mx end times.

The code I'm using is

```
;with Ranges as ( 
    select FUser_id,FloginDt,FlogoutDt
    from #AgentResults2 
    union all 
        select r.FUser_id,r.FloginDt,t.FLogoutdt
    from 
        Ranges r 
            inner join 
        #AgentResults2  t 
            on 
                r.FUser_id = t.FUser_Id and DATEDIFF(ms,r.Flogoutdt,t.FloginDt) = 0
), 
ExtendedRanges as ( 
select FUser_id,MIN(FloginDt) as FloginDt,Flogoutdt
from Ranges 
group by FUser_ID,Flogoutdt
) 
select FUser_Id,FloginDt,MAX(Flogoutdt) 
from ExtendedRanges 
group by FUser_id,FloginDt 
order by 1
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Maybe search for SQL overlapping ranges, e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345910/merge-rows-based-on-date-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever for pointing me to the other question. After looking at the probelm statement I was pretty happy - thinking that's it.But after making a corresponding code, I did not see expected result. The other question has a trick which is to combine the next day in the same row, however mine is two fold 1) if of the same millisecond include in the same row. 2) if less than endtime still include and make one row. It does not fully fit my situation. I'm attaching the code I've used in next comment.

Comment: if you're posting complex code, it would be better to edit your question so that you can format it properly.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Continuing from above - please see my code that I used based on the other question ';with Ranges as ( 
select FUser_id,FloginDt,FlogoutDt
from #AgentResults2 
union all 
select r.FUser_id,r.FloginDt,t.FLogoutdt
from 
Ranges r 
inner join 
#AgentResults2  t 
on 
r.FUser_id = t.FUser_Id and DATEDIFF(ms,r.Flogoutdt,t.FloginDt) = 0
), 
ExtendedRanges as ( 
select FUser_id,MIN(FloginDt) as FloginDt,Flogoutdt
from Ranges 
group by FUser_ID,Flogoutdt
) 
select FUser_Id,FloginDt,MAX(Flogoutdt) 
from ExtendedRanges 
group by FUser_id,FloginDt 
'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has got it:

```
;With Ranges as (
    select
        a1.FUser_Id,a1.FLoginDt,a1.FLogoutDt
    from
        #AgentResults2 a1
            left join
        #AgentResults2 a_nooverlap_early
            on
                a1.FUser_id = a_nooverlap_early.FUser_id and
                a_nooverlap_early.FLoginDt < a1.FLoginDt and
                a_nooverlap_early.FLogoutDt >= a1.FLoginDt
    where
        a_nooverlap_early.FUser_id is null
    union all
    select r.FUser_Id,r.FLoginDt,a1.FLogoutDt
    from
        Ranges r
            inner join
        #AgentResults2 a1
            on
                r.FUser_id = a1.FUser_Id and
                r.FLogoutDt >= a1.FLoginDt and
                a1.FLogoutDt > r.FLogoutDt
)
select FUser_id,FLoginDt,MAX(FLogoutDt) as FLogoutDt from Ranges group by FUser_id,FLoginDt
```

The first part of the `Ranges` CTE finds all time periods that have a `FLoginDt` that isn't overlapped by another range. The recursive portion of the CTE then tries to find any other time periods that overlap the `FLogoutDt` of these periods, and takes the later `FLogoutDt`. The final select then takes the latest found `FLogoutDt` for any particular `FUser_id`,`FLoginDt` combination - which should be the entire period for which overlaps exist.

I also re-written your sample data so that `SET DATEFORMAT DMY` wasn't required - the date format I've shown will always safely/unambiguously be converted to `datetime` by SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE #AgentResults2  (FUser_id  varchar(48), FLoginDt datetime, FLogoutDt DateTime)

Insert Into #AgentResults2 (FUser_id , FLoginDt, FLogoutDt ) 
select '30001','2012-02-17T08:09:23.117','2012-02-17T08:39:28.527' union all
select '30001','2012-02-17T08:50:26.087','2012-02-17T09:31:32.040' union all
select '30001','2012-02-17T10:28:42.430','2012-02-17T10:54:13.880' union all
select '30001','2012-02-17T10:59:20.567','2012-02-17T12:00:36.030' union all
select '30001','2012-02-17T12:32:15.473','2012-02-17T14:15:36.547' union all
select '30001','2012-02-17T12:49:48.177','2012-02-17T14:10:01.097' union all
select '30001','2012-02-17T14:30:49.293','2012-02-17T15:41:02.387' union all
select '30001','2012-02-17T15:44:05.800','2012-02-17T16:01:33.613' union all
select '39300','2012-02-17T08:06:31.250','2012-02-17T15:51:31.930' union all
select '39300','2012-02-17T10:15:08.923','2012-02-17T10:21:29.833' union all
select '39363','2012-02-17T09:58:44.287','2012-02-17T11:20:08.950' union all
select '39363','2012-02-17T11:20:29.203','2012-02-17T13:27:36.717' union all
select '39363','2012-02-17T13:27:36.717','2012-02-17T15:05:12.383' union all
select '39363','2012-02-17T15:05:31.527','2012-02-17T16:57:13.733' union all
select '39363','2012-02-17T16:57:44.640','2012-02-17T17:59:20.273' union all
select '39395','2012-02-17T09:37:14.353','2012-02-17T10:15:52.397' union all
select '39395','2012-02-17T10:15:28.427','2012-02-17T10:58:47.080' union all
select '39395','2012-02-17T10:57:03.590','2012-02-17T11:53:47.933' union all
select '39395','2012-02-17T11:51:31.567','2012-02-17T14:26:27.640' union all
select '39395','2012-02-17T14:31:30.247','2012-02-17T16:04:44.217' union all
select '39395','2012-02-17T16:10:49.013','2012-02-17T16:11:26.983' union all
select '39395','2012-02-17T16:17:16.813','2012-02-17T17:55:47.187' union all
select '39395','2012-02-17T16:55:25.900','2012-02-17T17:26:07.310';
```

Comment: Haven't analysed your script thoroughly yet, just tested, and it doesn't seem to cover all cases so far. The `39300` rows should merge into one (I think), but they remain separate rows in your script's output. Also I added this row: `select '30001','2012-02-17T08:39:28.527','2012-02-17T08:39:33.117' union all`, which, I expected, should have extended the `30001`'s first range, and it didn't (the script seemed to have ignored it).

Comment: @AndriyM - I had one comparison (should have had `>=` rather than `>`) slightly wrong, I think, but am unable to reproduce you 39300 issue - I only get one row in the output.

Comment: Nothing's wrong now, both issues are gone. I must say, this is very nice! My version used ROW_NUMBER(), and the resulting query proved much heavier in the end.